# Great 21st century bands worth listening to?

Tags: rock, similar-artists, the-beatles, pink-floyd, led-zeppelin

Can anyone recommend any good (present) rock bands of the like of *Tame Impala, Muse, The Heavy, and the Rival Sons*? These are the only 21st century bands that I listen to regularly.

Other bands to take into consideration before recommending:

*The Beatles, Pink Floyd, The Doors, Cream, Led Zeppelin, The Who, The Jimi Hendrix Exp, Rolling Stones, The Beach Boys, The Yardbirds, King Crimson, Yes, Queen, Electric Light Orchestra*... etc. I think you get the idea.

Basically any current band with influence from 60's and early 70's rock would be appreciated. Note I didn't mention any hard rock bands. Thanks in advance! Really look forward to listening to good music from this generation of artists.

Comment: There's a band called The Darkness that have a very Retro-70's guitar sound, very reminiscent of early Deep Purple or Whitesnake.  But they're sorta Pop-Rock so you may not dig it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the heavy rock side I would suggest the very young band *YAK*: they released their first album "Alas Salvation" on 2016. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpGfeTtxoaVSLQ2XqCbfcMA) you'll find their youtube channel, where you can taste some of their tunes.

On the psych side I recommend the band *Temples*: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs4i41cOv0s) you'll find their debut single (2012), but all their "Sun Structures" album (2014) is great.

And, oh, maybe they're not *only* 21st century band, but you should listen to *The Brian Jonestown Massacre*. They release almost one album a year, some new singles will be out in mid-january. They cover almost *all* the band you mentioned - you should really listen to them.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the young austrian Band *Mother's Cake*. They sound really a lot like classic 70's rock. I saw them at a festival this summer and was quite impressed. Check out this 6-track [live video](https://youtu.be/sOd154X302Y) for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a french band that play's 70s psychedelic blues rock you may like.

[image: Cheap Wine]

A link to their first hit: [Cheap Wine - I Come Back From Tomorrow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGebvp-quAk)